# upload files with ajax and node.js without express

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, multipartform-data, formidable

Hello guys i'm trying send files with ajax and node but i don't find the info that show me how do!!, i'm now built a script but me can follow more

```
var server=http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(req.url==='/upload'){
        if(req.method==='OPTIONS'){//OPTIONS is the method that show in the server when i send files
            req.on('data', function(a){
                console.log(a);//i dont know what are?? after to here!!
            });
        }
    }
});
```

i have listened of some module like formidable, [multipart](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty), and [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) but i can't run its

Thanks

i can solved it with FORMIDABLE :) look the next code:

```
var server=http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if(req.url==='/upload'){
        var headers = {};
              // IE8 does not allow domains to be specified, just the *
              // headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = req.headers.origin;
              headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
              headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
              headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = false;
              headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = '86400'; // 24 hours
              headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept";
        if(req.method==='OPTIONS'){
              res.writeHead(200, headers);
              res.end();
        }else if(req.method==='POST'){
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
                files = [],
                fields = [];
            form.uploadDir = '/home/sonick7/';//direccion donde va a ser gusradado

            form.on('field', function(field, value) {
                fields.push([field, value]);
              })
              .on('file', function(field, file) {
                console.log(file.name, file.size, file.type, file.path)
                files.push([field, file]);
              })
              .on('end', function() {
                console.log('Upload terminado ');
                res.writeHead(200, headers);
                res.end();
              });
            form.parse(req);//no se que hace eso y para que sirve el modulo util?
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE AND SOLVED

```
let server=http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    if(req.url==='/upload'){
        let headers = {}
              // IE8 does not allow domains to be specified, just the *
            headers={
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':false,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age':'86400', // 24 hours
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept'
              }
        if(req.method==='OPTIONS'){
              res.writeHead(200, headers)
              res.end()
        }else if(req.method==='POST'){
            let form=new formidable.IncomingForm(),
                files=[],
                fields=[]
            form.uploadDir='/home/sonick7/'

            form.on('field', (field, value)=>{
                fields.push([field, value])
            })
            .on('file', (field, file)=>{
                files.push([field, file])
            })
            .on('end', ()=>{
                console.log(files, fields, 'FT here awefwa', __filename)
                console.log('Upload terminado ')
                res.writeHead(200, headers)
                res.end()
            })
            form.parse(req)
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you received the request from you client with `OPTIONS` it probably means the client send CORS request first. I'm not sure which client library are you using, AFAKI AngularJS will send CROS request within each Ajax request.

So what you need to do on server side would handle this `OPTIONS` request, tell the client this is a valid CROS request, then the client should send the file upload request (`POST` maybe).

The code below is what I'm using in my project to handle CORS requests in *DEV* environment with `express` module, which means it allows request from any origin. In production environment you need to check the origin header and accept those you trust.

```
    app.configure(function () {
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            var oneof = false;
            if (req.headers.origin) {
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                oneof = true;
            }
            if (req.headers['access-control-request-method']) {
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
                oneof = true;
            }
            if (req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) {
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Authentication');
                oneof = true;
            }
            if (oneof) {
                res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
                res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
                res.header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="files.json"');
            }
            if (oneof && req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
                res.send(200);
            }
            else {
                next();
            }
        });
    });
```